# Laravel: Named route not found

Tags: laravel, routes

I have the following named route in **routes.php**:

```
Route::get('/', 'DefaultController@index', array('as' => 'home'));
```

Then, I try to get a link to the route in another view (404.blade.php), based on [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes):

```
<a href="{{URL::route('home')}}">Go to homepage</a>
```

However, the page with the code above thows this: **Error in exception handler: Route [home] not defined**. I tried using simply `route('home')` as well.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [syntax for named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes) is a bit different

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'DefaultController@index'));
```

Comment: Yes, my bad, I thought I could just use the "controller@action" syntax and add extra options in `array()`. Guess not. Anyway, thanks.